# iOS - get URL of an image i clicked on in a UIWebView via JavaScript

Tags: javascript, iphone, ios, objective-c, uiwebview

I'm not sure if i'm on the good path, but I injected some **javascript** to notify me via `webView:shouldStartLoadWithRequest:navigationType` whenever a `touch event` happens in a UIWebView. I am able to recover a target object from the touches event but I am not sure where to proceed from there.

What I inject:

```
[webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:
@"function MyFunction(e){document.location='http://null/'+e.touches[0].target;}
window.ontouchstart=function(e){MyFunction(e)}"
];
```

Answer (score 0):

If your requirement is to get the action whenever the user touches hyperlinks, phone numbers, address or so, then in the delegate webView:shouldStartLoadWithRequest:navigationType you will get the url string whenever such an action occurs using [[request URL] absoluteString], which you may handle as per your need. Also you will get the corresponding navigation type from navigationType.